# d3 js fast event invoking issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to ask whether someone of you had similar problem with d3 JS, when you invoking JS events too fast and they didn't trigger.

For example, you have a table and within that table there's a div element and you bind 2 events for each cell - 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'. Mouse enter for tooltipShow() function - mouse leave for **tooltipHide() function.**

```
<div id="tableWrapper">
<table id="myTable">
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>

<tr><td>Some data</td></tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="tooltip" style="visibility: hidden">Some info</div>
```

and **D3 js function** which applyies events for each  element

```
function initTableEvents(){
     var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip");
     d3.selectAll("#myTable td")
        .on('mouseenter', function(){tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")})
        .on('mouseleave',tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden"));
}
```

So, if I move mouse through all cells slowly - everything works fine (tooltip shows and hides). But when I move a bit faster tooltip appears, but not hides. It seems that 'mouseleave' event triggers and tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden") calls, but there is no result in browser.
I also added log messages with time in order to track what is going on. In this case hidding doesn't work:

```
Log msg
show tooltip 1463473895614
hide tooltip 1463473895622
show tooltip 1463473895622
hide tooltip 1463473895640
show tooltip 1463473895641
hide tooltip 1463473895650
show tooltip 1463473895650
hide tooltip 1463473895654
show tooltip 1463473895655
hide tooltip 1463473895665
show tooltip 1463473895665
hide tooltip 1463473895670
```

and for this it works:

```
Log msg
show tooltip 1463474018834
hide tooltip 1463474018874
show tooltip 1463474018874
hide tooltip 1463474018890
show tooltip 1463474018890
hide tooltip 1463474018916
show tooltip 1463474018916
hide tooltip 1463474018961
show tooltip 1463474018962
hide tooltip 1463474018989
show tooltip 1463474018989
hide tooltip 1463474019003
show tooltip 1463474019003
hide tooltip 1463474019034
show tooltip 1463474019034
hide tooltip 1463474019068
```

Is anyone had a such/similar issue?

Comment: can you mock up an example so we can test ? Preferably in JSFiddle. Also, try using mouseout rather than mouseleave maybe

Comment: Did the answer help ? Would help get an answer if you replied and provided an example

Comment: I tried to do example in JSFiddle, as 'thatOneGuy' recomended. It seems that problem was not related to mouse events so as in JSFiddle it worked fine. I started look depper in project and found that we use async.queue for sending request to server, processing result and so on. In the end of result processing we change tooltip visibility to visible. So, if I move mouse to fast through all cells my requests queue increasing. In the moment when mouse it out of the table JS is processesing a queue and the last action in this queue is 'show tooltip'.

Answer (score 1):

This may be your problem. See this link : http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/

Try using `mouseout` rather than `mouseleave`.

```
function initTableEvents(){
     var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip");
     d3.selectAll("#myTable td")
        .on('mouseenter', function(){tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")})
        .on('mouseout',tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden"));
}
```

> mouseout()
>
> 1 - When mouse enters the “outerBox”, no event will fire.
>
> 2 - When mouse leaves the “outerBox”, and enters “innerBox”, fire the
>   “outerBox” event.
>
> 3 - When mouse leaves the “innerBox”, and enters “outerBox”, fire the
>   “innerBox” event, follow by the “outerBox” event.
>
> 4 - When mouse leaves to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.
>
> mouseleave()
>
> 1 - When mouse enters the “outerBox”, no event will fire.
>
> 2 - When mouse leaves the “outerBox”, and enters “innerBox”, no event
>   will fire.
>
> 3 - When mouse leaves the “innerBox”, and enters “outerBox”, fire the
>   “innerBox” event.
>
> 4 - When mouse leaves to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.

Specifically point 2 on each of them. You want an event to fire when leaving the outerbox(current cell) and enters the innerbox (next cell). So this will work using `mouseout()` rather than `mouseleave()`

Example from page :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 #mouseout-outerBox1, #mouseleave-outerBox1,
 #mouseout-outerBox2, #mouseleave-outerBox2{
  margin:8px;
  border:1px groove #999966;
  background-color : #999966;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  color:white;
 }
 #mouseout-innerBox2, #mouseleave-innerBox2{
  margin:8px 8px 8px 16px;
  border:1px groove #0000FF;
  background-color : #0000FF;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  color:white;
 }
 span{
  padding:8px;
 }
 .content{
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
 }
 .container1{
  float:left;
  padding-right:16px;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>jQuery mouseout() vs mouseleave() example</h1>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container1">
   <span>mouseout() - no child element</span>
   <div id="mouseout-outerBox1">OuterBox
   </div>
   <span id="mouseout-msg1">#mouseout is fired : 0</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container1">
     <span>mouseleave() - no child element</span>
   <div id="mouseleave-outerBox1">OuterBox
   </div>
   <span id="mouseleave-msg1">#mouseleave is fired : 0</span>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="content">
  <div class="container1">
   <span>mouseout() - with child elements</span>
   <div id="mouseout-outerBox2">OuterBox
    <div id="mouseout-innerBox2">InnerBox
    </div>
   </div>
   <span id="mouseout-outer-msg2">#mouseout outer is fired : 0</span>
          <br/>
   <span id="mouseout-inner-msg2">#mouseout inner is fired : 0</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container1">
     <span>mouseleave() - with child elements</span>
   <div id="mouseleave-outerBox2">OuterBox
    <div id="mouseleave-innerBox2">InnerBox
    </div>
   </div>
   <span id="mouseleave-outer-msg2">#mouseleave outer is fired : 0</span>
          <br/>
   <span id="mouseleave-inner-msg2">#mouseleave inner is fired : 0</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//example 1
var mouseout1=1;
$('#mouseout-outerBox1').mouseout(function(event) {
  $('#mouseout-msg1').text('#mouseout is fired : ' + mouseout1++)
});

var mouseleave1=1;
$('#mouseleave-outerBox1').mouseleave(function(event) {
  $('#mouseleave-msg1').text('#mouseleave is fired : ' + mouseleave1++)
});

//example 2
var mouseoutouter2=1;
$('#mouseout-outerBox2').mouseout(function(event) {
  $('#mouseout-outer-msg2').text('#mouseout outer is fired : ' + mouseoutouter2++)
});

var mouseoutinner2=1;
$('#mouseout-innerBox2').mouseout(function(event) {
  $('#mouseout-inner-msg2').text('#mouseout inner is fired : ' + mouseoutinner2++)
});

var mouseleaveouter2=1;
$('#mouseleave-outerBox2').mouseleave(function(event) {
  $('#mouseleave-outer-msg2')
         .text('#mouseleave outer is fired : ' + mouseleaveouter2++)
});

var mouseleaveinner2=1;
$('#mouseleave-innerBox2').mouseleave(function(event) {
  $('#mouseleave-inner-msg2')
         .text('#mouseleave inner is fired : ' + mouseleaveinner2++)
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would recommend changing `mouseenter` to `mouseover` also. I don't think I have ever had to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as of yet but there will be a need sometime I am sure.

Comment: this is just a theory. If you provide a working example we can test